# Triangular / Curved shape bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I am using d3 to achieve this chart.

[image: Custom Bar Chart]

First I thought it is an area chart but the ux said it is a customized / curved chart. So far I am stuck on using corner-radius which is not enough curved. The image is created from sketch then invision so there is no css available on the inspect mode.

Comment: If I was designing the bars, I'd write a function to draw a line between three points (data point, data point - spread, data point + spread) and use curved interpolation and fill. The +/- spread points would always be set to y= 0. I don't have the time to write it for you, but it's an interesting chart idea.

Comment: can you provide sample links of curved interpolation? Yes it is but hard to do :D

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/ced1b9b18bd8192d2c898884033b5529